# Do the vikings watching everybody die in "Death from Above" ever play any role?

Tags: starcraft-2

Starcraft II, Heart of the Swarm.

While playing "Death from Above", I couldn't help but notice a couple vikings slacking off:

[image: Cropped screenshot of minimap with four groups of three units circled]

As far as I am concerned, they never actually attack me. They just sit there watching the show. I'm not entirely sure if this makes any difference depending on the difficulty.

I didn't bother attacking them. And they sure didn't bother harassing me either.

Now then, obviously they're very clever Terrans for not bugging The Swarm, but, do they play **any** role other than troll their comrades?

Answer (score 6):

I think they're just there to prevent you from going the route around most of the enemy base (i.e. you don't assault it from the southeast). IIRC there's even one message telling you that you should avoid the vikings (and one of the reasons you're given some Mutalisks a bit into the mission).

Comment: To prevent me from assaulting from the south-east? But they're just three vikings - surely I can kill them right away? (or are they immortal?). Well, not only that - they're too far away, so I can still assault without being intercepted by them I think.

Comment: Yeah possible. It's been a few days, but I'm quite sure you don't start with the Mutalisks immediately, so no anti-air initially. I guess they're still meant to fly at least some pattern, and possibly respawn as well or something like that.

Comment: I imagine they're not immortal, they probably either respawn, or are rebuilt in the enemy base (probably in greater numbers)

Answer (score 1):

On a brutal play through they never made there way in, if you send overlords to them they will destroy them but won't make any move to destroy the base. They are effectively decoration.
My guess would be a bug or someone overlooked them on the campaign design team.